# Can iPhone, Android, or WP7 Phone Devices work without a Service Plan?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7

I am wondering if any of these phone devices can function without a phone service plan (SIM card) similar to how an iPad or tablets work by just hooking into a Wifi spot?

Comment: Off topic, but also worth noting that you _can_ make calls over wifi if you install a SIP client. As @SevaAlekseyev points out, an iPod touch can behave very much like a phone :)

Comment: I have a Samsung Focus that I can't use because I'm a VZW customer.  My Trophy has Mango, so I use the Focus to test apps in NoDo.  Works great on WiFi.

As a side note, since the Focus doesn't get what it's worth from eBay, I also use it as a promotional device for WP7 by loaning it to friends with ATT so they can see the greatness for themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes for iPhone.  I have an iPhone 3G that has no SIM card and it works fine on WiFi (except you can't use SMS nor make cellular calls of course).

I also have an Android G1 (unlocked) that works fine on WiFi with no SIM card, but it did require a SIM card with data plan in order to get setup out of the box.  After that initial setup it doesn't seem to care that it only has WiFi and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for the iPhone only: yes. I would assume that the other phones would work as well, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for a few android phones - myTouch, G1, Droid, no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows Phone works just fine without a SIM, as long as you have wireless.  Android as well, however some of the Sprint phones we got for development wouldn't let you skip the "get a service plan" step at startup, so your mileage may vary for Android.  You should ask specifically if that model works without a plan... the guys at the store should be able to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on all devices, as long as you have a SIM card installed (no plan required however).